# Asymptotic expansion around infinity for inverse cdf of normal distribution

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion, distributions, asymptotics

I'm trying to get a asymptotic expansion as $x\rightarrow\infty$ for a particular expression. I have

```
f[x_] := 1/x*InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1 - Exp[-x^(1/4)]];
```

As $x\rightarrow\infty$, we have $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ but I am interested in how it behaves at $\infty$. I tried using `AsymptoticSolve` and `Series` but neither seems to get me a nice expansion.

How can I proceed with this? I realize some mathematical insight might also be required before Mathematica can solve this for me.

Comment: Just using `Series`, `Assuming` that $x>0$, and doing `FullSimplify` gives me $\frac{\sqrt{2 \sqrt[4]{x}-\log \left(\pi  \left(4 \sqrt[4]{x}-2 \log (2 \pi )\right)\right)}}{x}$. Using series again, one can get the leading term $\sqrt{2} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{7/8}$. More accurately $\sqrt{2} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{7/8}-\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{9/8} \log \left(256 \pi ^4 x\right)}{8 \sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @yarchik thanks for your comment. Somehow, I still have a giant mess in a square root (and it's different from what's under your square root), even after FullSimplify and Series again. Could you post your code as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [assumptions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) and [an immediate assignment](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/39-immediate-and-delayed-values.html):

```
f[x_] = Assuming[x >= 0,
          1/x*InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1 - Exp[-x^(1/4)]] // 
          FullSimplify]

(*    -((Sqrt[2] InverseErfc[2 - 2 E^-x^(1/4)])/x)    *)

Assuming[x >= 0, Asymptotic[f[x], x -> ∞]]

(*    Sqrt[2]/x^(7/8) - (8 Log[2] + 4 Log[π] + Log[x])/(
      8 Sqrt[2] x^(9/8)) - (
      64 Log[2]^2 + 64 Log[2] Log[π] + 16 Log[π]^2 - 
      64 Log[2 π] + 16 Log[2] Log[x] + 8 Log[π] Log[x] + 
      Log[x]^2)/(256 Sqrt[2] x^(11/8)) - (1/(
      4096 Sqrt[2] x^(
      13/8)))(512 Log[2]^3 + 768 Log[2]^2 Log[π] + 
      384 Log[2] Log[π]^2 + 64 Log[π]^3 - 
      512 Log[2] Log[2 π] - 256 Log[π] Log[2 π] - 
      256 Log[2 π]^2 + 192 Log[2]^2 Log[x] + 
      192 Log[2] Log[π] Log[x] + 48 Log[π]^2 Log[x] - 
      64 Log[2 π] Log[x] + 24 Log[2] Log[x]^2 + 
      12 Log[π] Log[x]^2 + Log[x]^3)    *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = Assuming[x >= 0, 
  1/x*InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1 - Exp[-x^(1/4)]] // FullSimplify]

(* -((Sqrt[2] InverseErfc[2 - 2 E^-x^(1/4)])/x) *)

f1[x] = Asymptotic[f[x], x -> ∞] // Simplify[#, x >= 0] &

(* Sqrt[2 x^(1/4) - Log[2 π (2 x^(1/4) + Log[1/(2 π)])]]/x *)

f2[x] = Assuming[x >= 0, Asymptotic[f[x], x -> ∞] // FullSimplify]

(* (64 (128 x^(3/4) + 4 Log[2 π]^2 - 32 Sqrt[x] Log[4 π] + 
      4 Log[2 π] Log[4 π] - Log[4 π]^3 - 
      4 x^(1/4) (4 Log[2]^2 - 4 Log[2 π] + Log[π] Log[16 π])) - 
   Log[x] (16 (32 Sqrt[x] - 4 Log[2 π] + 8 x^(1/4) Log[4 π] + 
         3 Log[4 π]^2) + 4 (4 x^(1/4) + Log[64 π^3]) Log[x] + 
      Log[x]^2))/(4096 Sqrt[2] x^(13/8)) *)
```

Plotting the functions, `f2` appears to be a better approximation

```
Plot[Evaluate@{f1[x], f2[x], f[x]}, {x, 5, 40}, PlotLegends ->
  Placed[{"f1", "f2", "f"}, {.5, .5}]]
```

[image]

However, looking at the relative error, `f1` is better for larger values of `x`

```
LogPlot[Evaluate@{(f1[x] - f[x])/f[x], (f2[x] - f[x])/f[x]}, {x, 5, 150},
 WorkingPrecision -> 50,
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[{"f1", "f2"}, {.75, .75}]]
```

[image]

The crossover occurs at

```
FindRoot[f1[x] == f2[x], {x, 90}]

(* {x -> 91.366} *)
```

a [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) function could be used to switch between the approximations.